# Apply gradient to all images that have inline background image url?

Tags: css

When I put linear-gradient and url together, it works fine:
HTML:

```
<div class="image" style="height:400px;width:400px;">
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(
          rgba(0, 26, 56, 0.7), 
          rgba(0, 0, 69, 0.7)
        ),
        url('http://incolor.inebraska.com/tgannon/grfs/birds256_oth/OwlGrH256x256.jpg');
}
```

JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/5mb6hu3u/
But when I use it separated, it won't work:
HTML:

```
<div class="image" style="height:400px;width:400px;background: url('http://incolor.inebraska.com/tgannon/grfs/birds256_oth/OwlGrH256x256.jpg')">
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    background: 
        linear-gradient(
          rgba(0, 26, 56, 0.7), 
          rgba(0, 0, 69, 0.7)
        );
}
```

JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/5mb6hu3u/1/
There's a lot of images that I need to apply the gradient, any way to do that without using `<img>` tags?

Comment: In your first case you have a comma-separated list of backgrounds, all of which will be applied in browsers that support CSS3 multiple backgrounds. In your second case you have _two_ separate style rules, with one overriding the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know it can't be done, as both gradients and images are essentially `background-image`, and the only way to define multiple background images is with a comma separated list.

A simple workaround is to put the gradient on a pseudo element, so it will appear above the image ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/v2x3v3La/2/)):

```
.image {
    position: relative;
}

.image::before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: 
        linear-gradient(
          rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.7), 
          rgba(0, 0, 51, 0.7)
        );
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: Ori Drori, would you be able to tell me why content:''; is essential to this code work?

Comment: Pseudo elements ([`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore) and [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter)) are not rendered, unless they have some sort of [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content). So the minimum requirement is empty content - `content: ''`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not necessarily true, yet granted this was answered 3 years ago.

I believe **that depends on what server side language you're using, but it usually should fit right inline.**

Here's an example on one of my applications below was written in php tags:

```
style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent, #000), url({$sub_cat_img})"
```